# How to split a list in two while iterating over it and place the results in a tuple using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible if i have an enumerable

```
Input :[1,2,3,4]
Output :([1,3],[2,4])
```

to iterate once over it and start putting odd numbers in a sequence/list/whatever  and even in another and at the end placing the two sequences in a tuple?

I have tried something like:

```
class Elem
{
int x;
}
(rez1,rez2)=from value in Generator()
            let odds=Enumerable.Empty<Elem>()
            let evens=Enumerable.Empty<Elem>()
            select(value%2==0?odds.**append**(value):odds.**append**(value))
```

How can i direct the select over one element of the tuple or the other for each element?Can i have two mutable lists inside a linq query?

P.S I am trying to achieve something like (similar to Haskell) :

```
select element ->  predicate True -> goes to first element of result tuple
                   predicate False-> goes to second element of result tuple
```

Everything in 0(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create tuple like the following. Run two queries for odd and even values.

```
Tuple.Create(input.Where(c => c % 2 == 1).ToArray(), input.Where(c => c % 2 == 0).ToArray());
```

Comment: Yes i know i can do it with two querries.But i was wondering if i can create the tuple on the fly as the final result of the querry.

Answer (score 5):

Here a approach with 2 `List<int>` and only one iteration

```
List<int> input = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>(), new List<int>() };
input.ForEach(x => result[x % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1].Add(x));
```

---

Another approach with Linq - a bit slower because of the extra grouping - I would choose the first one

```
int[][] result = input.GroupBy(x => x % 2).Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it using LINQ? and not define the List?Just the result?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian added

Comment: Wow that is really neat.

Answer (score 2):

For a list input (not a `List<List>>`) we can use `GroupBy` to group it by predicate function and `Select` to project the `IGrouping` to `List`:

```
List<List<int>> buckets = input.GroupBy(func).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

For a `List<List>>` input we would need to flatten the list with `.SelectMany` before using the samae method as above:

```
var func = new Func<int, bool>(x => x % 2 == 0);
List<List<int>> buckets = input.SelectMany(e => e).GroupBy(func).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

This approach:

```
var tuple = Tuple.Create(new List<int>(), new List<int>());
var func = new Func<int, bool>(x => x % 2 == 0);
List<List<int>> buckets = input.Select(e => 
{
   func(e)? tuple.Item1.Add(e) : tuple.Item2.Add(e);
   return e;
}).ToList();
```

Is not really a good one.

LINQ is a query language and query is something that should return result not *create* result. So there is no reason to use `Select` for creating elements or adding them to collection, instead we can run our query get the result and save it to whatever object/format we need.

If you need Tuple then save query result of the first two Lists to `Tuple`:

```
var tuple = Tuple.Create(buckets[0], buckets[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The groupby clause pretty much solves it but  it creates an enumerable of groupings which i cant dump in a tuple.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Just create Tuple in the end and put result there. The whole thing is pretty much `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it like in Haskell, then do it like in Haskell. Haskell does not iterate over a sequence, it defines a tuple elements as sets with certain properties. You should do the same:

```
var values = Generator();
Tuple.Create(
    values.Where(    /* define what you want for the first set */  ),
    values.Where(    /* define what you want for the second set */  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something very complicated:

```
        var list = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        var result = list.Select(
                o => new
                {
                    A = o % 2 == 1 ? o : (int?)null,
                    B = o % 2 == 0 ? o : (int?)null
                })
            .GroupBy(o => o.A != null)
            .Select(o => o.Select(t => t.A ?? t.B ?? 0).ToList())
            .ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(result[1]);
```

Comment: Yes this is something similar to what i was looking for.I didn't want auxiliary variables defined.